# Optimize a SQL Server left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Licitaciones L 
LEFT JOIN CPVLicitaciones C ON L.IDLicitacion = C.IDLicitador
WHERE (DateInserted>='2019-12-11' or DateUpdated>='2019-12-11')
```

The query takes about two minutes and there are not so many records
I would like to optimize this query but I don't have the knowledge to do it.

Comment: We'd need to know what indexes you have defined on those tables and to see an execution plan to offer any guidance. Also how many record are in the tables.

Comment: Do you need all columns of the tables because you are using asterisks (*) sign? At first, ı can recommend only use the required columns for your query and then you can upload the execution plan and we can analyze it https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: And you may find more expertise over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please go on this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176549/149623
and also go through this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZLC2_9.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.developer.doc/refs/rsdperformanceworkspaces.htm

Comment: And what tables do the `where` conditions come from?

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, the conditions comes from Licitaciones

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Licitaciones L 
    LEFT JOIN 
    CPVLicitaciones C ON 
        L.IDLicitacion = C.IDLicitador
WHERE DateInserted>='2019-12-11'

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM Licitaciones L 
    LEFT JOIN 
    CPVLicitaciones C ON 
        L.IDLicitacion = C.IDLicitador
WHERE DateUpdated>='2019-12-11'
```

Comment: The union works perfectly . The previous query spent two minutes to make the query now with the union takes four seconds. Thanks Mithun ambadi